# Months not display correctly with php

Tags: php

I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

I create  php loop to display next 3 years months.

My code:

```
<div class="input-group col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 search">
     <label class="bd-form-label">Dates</label>
     <select name="date" id="search_date">
       <?php                        
        echo '<option value="all">Any Month</option>';
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 36; $i++) {
          $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
          $label = date('F Y', $time);
          echo "<option value='$label'>$label</option>";
        }
       ?>
     /select>
 </div>
```

It does displaying all months but not February(2018-2019-2020)

[image]

Any feedback? Is it something with my code? Cause I can not find any errors

Comment: It's to do with the way you are incrementing months with `+%s months`. February is shorter than other months.

Comment: it's because feb is having 28/29 days only and you are adding one month every time that's why feb skipped

Comment: Thank you for that guys. But still with +%s months is not working @DarraghEnright

Comment: @Maria - That's what you wrote - I was just pointing out the issue, I haven't suggested a solution ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734891/4248328

Comment: @DarraghEnright I am sorry I thoughts thats kinf of solution because I have +%d months in my code not +%s    ;)

Comment: Every month at the end of the month.... same question is asked again and again.... don't base your date on the current date for each month, but on the first of the month

Comment: @Maria - ah yes, sorry, I meant to write `%d` - that's muscle memory kicking in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are at the end of month (october 30th). If you add a fixed time parameter to `strtotime` (beginning of current month, october 1st), february will appear on the list. The reason lies in how `strtotime` handles the "month" parameter.

```
<div class="input-group col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 search">
     <label class="bd-form-label">Dates</label>
     <select name="date" id="search_date">
       <?php                        
        echo '<option value="all">Any Month</option>';
        $start = strtotime('first day of this month');
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 36; $i++) {
          $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i), $start);
          $label = date('F Y', $time);
          echo "<option value='$label'>$label</option>";
        }
       ?>
     </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Added an answer using the DateTime class, which in my opinion looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Start your iteration with the first day of the current month to yield the right results:

```
<?php

    $date = new \DateTime('first day of this month');

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 36; $i++) {
        $date->modify("+1 months");
        echo $date->format('F Y');
    }

?>
```

Will output:

> November 2017
>   December 2017
>   January 2018
>   February 2018
>   March 2018
>   April 2018 ...

Answer (score 1):

**The "+1 month" issue with strtotime**

Considering the [following comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#111989) from the PHP Manual:

> As noted in several blogs, strtotime() solves the "+1 month" ("next month") issue on days that do
>   not exist in the subsequent month differently than other
>   implementations like for example MySQL.

```
<?php
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +1 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-03
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +2 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-31
?>

<?php
SELECT DATE_ADD( '2009-01-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH ); // MySQL:  2009-02-28
?>
```

**Solution:**

A better idea would be to use a different string than `+X month`.
Perhaps, a mm/dd format date `$i/01` (there always be the first day of the month) or use `mktime`.

```
$time = mktime(0,0,0,$i,1); //seconds, minutes, hours, month, day
```

> **Mktime - Month parameter** - The number of the month relative to the end of the previous year.
>   Values 1 to 12 reference the normal calendar months of the year in
>   question. Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference the
>   months in the previous year in reverse order, so 0 is December, -1 is
>   November, etc. **Values greater than 12 reference the appropriate month
>   in the following year(s)**.