# PHP strtotime ERROR

Tags: php, strtotime

It's really wired 
as on 30-APR-12

both :

```
date("M", strtotime("-2 months"));
date("M", strtotime("-1 months"));
```

giving me same result like :
Mar
Mar

on any other day it is ok. I'm too new to call it anything tell me what should i do?

I've XAMPP 1.7.4 package (PHP 5.3.5)

Comment: FOUND A SOLUTION [Solution_link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211824/php-strtotime-1month-2month) here.
using date("M", strtotime("-2 month", strtotime(date("F") . "1")) ) instead... don't know why?
If anybody kindly explain would be great... thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dates you are actually getting back are:

- 2012-03-01
- 2012-03-30

The behavior of `strtotime()` is a bit tricky when it comes to months like this.  If you go back two months, there is no 30th of February, so you end up on March 1st.  Back 1 month is the behavior you expect.

To fix this problem, just use the month portion when using `strtotime()`.

```
date('M', strtotime('-2 months', strtotime('2012-04-01')));
```

Just replace the year/month with the current one.

Comment: Thanks...i'm using date("M", strtotime("-$i month", strtotime(date("F") . "1")) ) instead