# PHP add 1 month to date

Tags: php, date

I've a function that returns url of 1 month before.

I'd like to display current selected month, but I cannot use simple current month, cause when user clicks link to 1 month back selected month will change and will not be current.

So, function returns August 2012

How do I make little php script that adds 1 month to that?

so far I've:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(tribe_get_previous_month_text()); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Strtotime -1month -2month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211824/php-strtotime-1month-2month)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simple method:

```
$next_month = strtotime('august 2012 next month');
```

better method:

```
$d = new Date('August 2012');
$next_month = $d->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

relevant docs: [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)  [date](http://php.net/date)   [dateinterval](http://php.net/dateinterval)

Comment: What makes the second method better?

Comment: strtotime just gives you a raw timestamp. the date/time object complex gives you an object on which you can easily do any other sort of manipulation, including more date 'math', plus get out that raw timestamp anytime you want.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'august 2012 next month'`?

Comment: @j08691: whops, right. changing the ->sub() to ->add() and adjusting var names.

Comment: so New Date constructs a date. In its value I put my function?

Comment: use DateTime instead of Date.

Comment: @glavić Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: I hope you have php version>= 5.2.0?

Comment: you cannot echo DateTime object, you have to use ->format('d.m.Y') to format the output...

Comment: @glavić yes I do. Datetime I was echoing it out, that's why the error. ty.

Comment: if you have php >= 5.4 you can put that in one line, like this > $d = (new DateTime('August 2012'))->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format('F Y');

Answer (score 7):

there are 3 options/answers

```
     $givendate is the given date (ex. 2016-01-20)

option 1:
        $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($givendate. ' + 1 month'));

option 2:
        $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($givendate. ' + 30 days'));

option 3:
        $number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m', strtotime($givendate)), date('Y', strtotime($givendate)));
        $date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2. ' + '.$number.' days'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can with the DateTime class and the DateTime::add() method:

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: tribe_get_previous_month_text() outputs a string. Will it work?

Comment: You'd have to put that in the constructor.. see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Worked great for me; thanks! I needed today + 1 Year.       $date = new DateTime();
      $date->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use the `strtotime` function on whatever input you have to arrive at April 2012 then apply the `date` and `strtotime` with an increment period of '+1 month'.

```
$x = strtotime($t);
$n = date("M Y",strtotime("+1 month",$x));
echo $n;
```

Here are the relevant sections from the PHP Handbook:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

This solution solves the additional issue of incrementing *any* amount of time to a time value.

Answer (score 2):

Hi In Addition to their answer. I think if you just want to get the next month based on the current date here's my solution.

```
$today = date("Y-m-01");

$sNextMonth = (int)date("m",strtotime($today." +1 months") );
```

Notice That i constantly define the day to 01 so that we're safe on getting the next month. if that is date("Y-m-d"); and the current day is 31 it will fail.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Date difference

```
$date1 = '2017-01-20';
$date2 = '2019-01-20';

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

echo $joining_months = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since we know that strtotime(+1 month) always adds 30 days it can be some troubles with dates ending with the day 31, 30 or 29 AND if you still want to stay within the last day of the next month.

So I wrote this over complicated script to solve that issue as well as adapting so that you can increase all type of formats like years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
function seetime($datetime, $p = '+', $i, $m = 'M', $f = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    
    /* 
    $datetime needs to be in format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS but hours, minutes and seconds are not required
    $p can only be "+" to increse or "-" to decrese
    $i is the amount you want to change
    $m is the type you want to change
    
    Allowed types:
    Y = Year
    M = Months
    D = Days
    W = Weeks
    H = Hours
    I = Minutes
    S = Seconds
    
    $f is the datetime format you want the result to be returned in
    
    */
    $validator_y = substr($datetime,0,4);
    $validator_m = substr($datetime,5,2);
    $validator_d = substr($datetime,8,2);
    
    if(checkdate($validator_m, $validator_d, $validator_y))
    {
        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime));
        #$p = either "+" to add or "-" to subtract
        if($p == '+' || $p == '-')
        {
            if(is_int($i))
            {
                if($m == 'Y')
                {
                    $year = date('Y', strtotime($datetime));
                    $rest = date('m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime));
                    
                    if($p == '+')
                    {
                        $ret = $year + $i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $ret = $year - $i;
                    }
                    
                    $str = $ret.'-'.$rest;
                    
                    return(date($f, strtotime($str)));
                }
                elseif($m == 'M')
                {
                    $year = date('Y', strtotime($datetime));
                    $month = date('n', strtotime($datetime));
                    $rest = date('d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime));
                    $his = date('H:i:s', strtotime($datetime));
                    if($p == '+')
                    {
                        $ret = $month + $i;
                        $ret = sprintf("%02d",$ret);
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $ret = $month - $i;
                        $ret = sprintf("%02d",$ret);
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    if($ret < 1)
                    {
                        $ret = $ret - $ret - $ret;
                        $years_back = floor(($ret + 12) / 12);
                        $monts_back = $ret % 12;
                        $year = $year - $years_back;
                        $month = 12 - $monts_back;
                        $month = sprintf("%02d",$month);
                        $new_date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$rest;
                        $ym = $year.'-'.$month;
                        
                        $validator_y = substr($new_date,0,4);
                        $validator_m = substr($new_date,5,2);
                        $validator_d = substr($new_date,8,2);
                        if(checkdate($validator_m, $validator_d, $validator_y))
                        {
                            return (date($f, strtotime($new_date)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $days = date('t',strtotime($ym));
                            $new_date = $ym.'-'.$days.' '.$his;
                            return (date($f, strtotime($new_date)));
                        }
                    }
                    if($ret > 12)
                    {
                        
                        $years_forw = floor($ret / 12);
                        $monts_forw = $ret % 12;
                        $year = $year + $years_forw;
                        $month = sprintf("%02d",$monts_forw);
                        $new_date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$rest;
                        $ym = $year.'-'.$month;
                        
                        $validator_y = substr($new_date,0,4);
                        $validator_m = substr($new_date,5,2);
                        $validator_d = substr($new_date,8,2);
                        if(checkdate($validator_m, $validator_d, $validator_y))
                        {
                            return (date($f, strtotime($new_date)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $days = date('t',strtotime($ym));
                            $new_date = $ym.'-'.$days.' '.$his;
                            return (date($f, strtotime($new_date)));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $ym = $year.'-'.$month;
                        $new_date = $year.'-'.$ret.'-'.$rest;
                        
                        $validator_y = substr($new_date,0,4);
                        $validator_m = substr($new_date,5,2);
                        $validator_d = substr($new_date,8,2);
                        if(checkdate($validator_m, $validator_d, $validator_y))
                        {
                            return (date($f, strtotime($new_date)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $ym = $validator_y . '-'.$validator_m;
                            $days = date('t',strtotime($ym));
                            $new_date = $ym.'-'.$days.' '.$his;
                            return (date($f, strtotime($new_date)));
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                elseif($m == 'D')
                {
                    return (date($f, strtotime($datetime.' '.$p.$i.' days')));
                }
                elseif($m == 'W')
                {
                    return (date($f, strtotime($datetime.' '.$p.$i.' weeks')));
                }
                elseif($m == 'H')
                {
                    return (date($f, strtotime($datetime.' '.$p.$i.' hours')));
                }
                elseif($m == 'I')
                {
                    
                    return (date($f, strtotime($datetime.' '.$p.$i.' minutes')));
                }
                elseif($m == 'S')
                {
                    return (date($f, strtotime($datetime.' '.$p.$i.' seconds')));
                }
                else
                {
                    return 'Fourth parameter can only be any of following: Valid Time Parameters Are: Y M D Q H I S';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 'Third parameter can only be a number (whole number)';
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Second parameter can only be + to add or - to subtract';
        }
    }
    else    
    {
        return 'Date is not a valid date';
    }   
    
}
```