# how to increment the current date which is in d/m/Y format by one month

Tags: php

i want to increment the current date by one month which is in d/m/Y format
but i have no idea about this,can any one give me a relevant example.

thanks in advance

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I'm pretty sure this could easily be found with a simple search on either google or this site.

Comment: why does the current date have to have a specific format?

Comment: @PLB: now now ;-) +1 anyway.

Comment: A duplicate of this question. You can find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324640/php-add-1-month-to-date

Comment: sorry for that i didnt find any relevant example with the above mentioned format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you do this:

```
$time = strtotime("+1 month", time());
$date = date("d/m/Y", $time);
```

Comment: Thank you Chris it working for my code.